# Hibernate Many-To-Many mapping with 3 level subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, subclass

I have the following UML diagram.

[image]

Since it is a manyToMany relation i need three tables to store the data:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    idObj BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(100),
    nomeUtente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Works(
    idObj BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nrIncarico int,
    annoIncarico int,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE UsersWorksRel(
    idGiudice BIGINT NOT NULL,
    idIncarico BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idGiudice) REFERENCES Users(idObj),
    FOREIGN KEY (idIncarico) REFERENCES Works(idObj)
);
```

In the AbstractPO i used the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, the Users also is ok, but i'm not able to annotate the Judge class...
My idea was to use the Judge class to have the manyToMany relation with the Works, like this:

```
public class Judge extends UserPO{

   private List<Works> incarichi;

   public Judge () {
        setTipo(TipologiaUtente.GIUDICE);
   }

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "UsersWorksRel", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "idGiudice", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idIncarico", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public List<Works> getIncarichi() {
        return incarichi;
    }

    public void setIncarichi(List<Works> incarichi) {
        this.incarichi = incarichi;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can annotate `UserPO` with `@MappedSuperclass` and `Judge` with `@Entity`. Or you can use hibernate inheritance mapping between `UserPO` and `Judge`.

Comment: I can't use `@MappedSuperclass` since i need to map it to the users table besause i have other users they are not judge. Please tell me more about hibernate ingeritance. I tries many examples but i was not able to arrange it.

Comment: In superclass `UserPO` you set data common to all subclasses like `Judge` and `Criminal`,`Victim`. @MappedSuperclass allows you to inherit not just data but also hibernate mappings. So fields in `UserPO` are mapped to columns in `Judge` table.

Comment: You need a few good tutorials to understand all this. I ca recommend [these tutorials](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/03/hibernate-3-on-baby-steps.html#.U7rrCZSSzdc)

Comment: I'll look the tutorial...but note, i need to be able to instantiate both, UserPO and Judge which map the users table, the Judge furthermore needs to map the UsersWorksRel for the manyToMany.

Comment: Tutorials explain all kinds of inheritance mapping. But if you wish I'll do your demands instead of you for reasonable fee.